# Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin'

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, web-services

Here i am consuming java rest webservices in asp.net,while calling service in asp.net i am using ajax to call webservice,below is the code i have used

```
 $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: 'http://localhost:9090/EmployeeService/employee/create',


            data: { id: 4, first_name:"narayan", last_name:"phone", email:"phone", phone:4545454545 },
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: OnSuccessCall,
            error: OnErrorCall
        });
```

when i run this i get error saying as below

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:9090/EmployeeService/employee/create. Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:64992' is therefore not allowed access.

i googled on this topic i found many answers saying i have to add a custom header (or set of headers) to an individual request and shows me code as below

```
$.ajax({
url: 'foo/bar',
headers: { 'x-my-custom-header': 'some value' }
});
```

or

```
$.ajaxSetup({
headers: { 'x-my-custom-header': 'some value' }
});

// Sends your custom header
$.ajax({ url: 'foo/bar' });

// Overwrites the default header with a new header
$.ajax({ url: 'foo/bar', headers: { 'x-some-other-header': 'some value' }     });
```

here what should i substitute for 'x-some-other-header' and "some value" according to my code.Is this the right way to solve this error or what is the other solution?.Please guide me i am very new to asp.net.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by giving access to cross-domain in server side.As the service was written in java using maven i made it to support cross domain by adding in web.xml page these filters

```
      <filter>
    <filter-name>CorsFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.apache.catalina.filters.CorsFilter</filter-class>
     </filter>
  <filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>CorsFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
  </filter-mapping>
```

By adding these in web.xml,i was able to solve the error.

Answer (score 0):

Are you purposely trying to submit a request to a different domain? The application port, which follows "localhost:", tends to change unless you set it as static. It seems like the port number has been changed to 64992 instead of 9090